# About the number of rational points of a curve over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and $b \in \mathbb{F}_{3^{n}}$ be an element such that $b^{\frac{3^{n}-1}{2}}=(-1)^{n+1}$ (we fix $n$ and $b$).

Let $C$ be the curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_{3^{n}}$ by the equation
$$y^{3^n+1}-y^2 = x^3 + bx.$$
I would like to compute the number of $\mathbb{F}_{3^{2nj}}$ -rational points of $C$ for $j \geq 1$ any integer.

Is there a good way to do this? I would appreciate any suggestions or information.

( I have already computed the case $j=1$ : I get
$$\#C(\mathbb{F}_{3^{2n}})=1+3^{n+1}+3^n(3^n-1)$$
by explicit computations of the equation above (the first "$1$" is for the point at infinity). However, the same computation is very complicated when $j$ is arbitrary...)

Comment: The mapping properties of the right hand side are trivial to analyze, and that leads to a formula in terms of a character sum over $y$ involving the l.h.s. divided by a constant. In a sense it is a quadratic form of $y$, but the usual characteristic two tricks didn't give anything useful looking right away. If I find more time, I will try again.